# Doctrine MongoDB Download file stored in base

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, symfony

i'd like to know how to get file stored in my mongoDB (driven with Symfony3/doctrine MongoDB), and make the client download them.

It's a bit hard to find informations on it.

can you Help me?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [whole chapter](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/storing-files-with-mongogridfs.html) in documentation with examples for both things you want to do.